# Users can't log in using new "Sign in with LinkedIn" OAuth screen

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Some of our users have reported that they are not able to log in to our app anymore when they try do so with "Sign in with LinkedIn". The app is a Cordova app for both iOS and Android that uses the LinkedIn SDK to handle the "Sign in with LinkedIn" functionality of our app.

This seems to be correlated with the new log in screen design that they get. I cannot reproduce this myself, as I'm still getting the old version of the login screen.

When they get the new screen they immediately get one or more emails saying something about a password reset. When they then enter their credentials and log in, they get some more emails about a password reset, totalling more than 10 messages in some cases! And they are still not able to complete the login and use our app.

The flow this user gets is as following:

1. After clicking "Sign in with LinkedIn" on our app, they get the login screen with the new design (which actually prompts to download the app)
2. As soon as "No thanks" is clicked, our user receives an email from your security team to reset it's password
3. Ignoring that e-mail and trying to log in with their credentials doesn't work (probably because you reset their password)
4. Now the user receives even more emails from you about resetting their password

I'm getting these reports since last week. I've got no idea if that correlates with a change LinkedIn has pushed to the OAuth login interaction. I've emailed with LI Support about this, but they have no idea about this new login screen and how to fix this, which is really annoying.

Just to clarify

- The old, regular "Sign in with LinkedIn" screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZOFQ.jpg
- The new screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMpvB.jpg